# Injecting $state (ui-router) into $http interceptor causes circular dependency

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

**What I'm trying to achieve**

I would like to to transition to a certain state (login) in case an $http request returns a 401 error. I have therefore created an $http interceptor.

**The problem**

When I am trying to insert '$state' into the interceptor I get a circular dependency. Why and how do i fix it?

**Code**

```
//Inside Config function

    var interceptor = ['$location', '$q', '$state', function($location, $q, $state) {
        function success(response) {
            return response;
        }

        function error(response) {

            if(response.status === 401) {
                $state.transitionTo('public.login');
                return $q.reject(response);
            }
            else {
                return $q.reject(response);
            }
        }

        return function(promise) {
            return promise.then(success, error);
        }
    }];

    $httpProvider.responseInterceptors.push(interceptor);
```

Answer (score 213, accepted):

### The Fix

Use the `$injector` service to get a reference to the `$state` service.

```
var interceptor = ['$location', '$q', '$injector', function($location, $q, $injector) {
    function success(response) {
        return response;
    }

    function error(response) {

        if(response.status === 401) {
            $injector.get('$state').transitionTo('public.login');
            return $q.reject(response);
        }
        else {
            return $q.reject(response);
        }
    }

    return function(promise) {
        return promise.then(success, error);
    }
}];

$httpProvider.responseInterceptors.push(interceptor);
```

### The Cause

[angular-ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) injects the `$http` service as a dependency into `$TemplateFactory` which then creates a circular reference to `$http` within the `$httpProvider` itself upon dispatching the interceptor.

The same circular dependency exception would be thrown if you attempt to inject the `$http` service directly into an interceptor like so.

```
var interceptor = ['$location', '$q', '$http', function($location, $q, $http) {
```

### Separation of Concerns

Circular dependency exceptions can indicate that there is a mixing of concerns within your application which could cause stability issues. If you find yourself with this exception you should take the time to look at your architecture to ensure you avoid any dependencies that end up referencing themselves.

### @Stephen Friedrich's answer

I agree with the answer below that using the `$injector` to directly get a reference to the desired service is not ideal and could be considered an anti pattern.

Emitting an event is a much more elegant and also decoupled solution.

Comment: How would this be adjusted for Angular 1.3, where there are 4 different functions passed into interceptors?

Comment: The usage would be the same, you inject the `$injector` service into your interceptor and call `$injector.get()` where you need to get the `$state` service.

Comment: I get $injectot.get("$state") as << not defined >>, could you please tell what may be the issue ?

Comment: This definitely is a lifesaver when it's a simple situation, but when you run into this it's a sign that you have indeed created a circular dependency somewhere in your code, which is easy to do in AngularJS with its DI. Misko Hevery explains it very well [in his blog](http://misko.hevery.com/2008/08/01/circular-dependency-in-constructors-and-dependency-injection/); highly recommend you read it to improve your code.

Comment: `$httpProvider.responseInterceptors.push` don't work anymore if you are using later versions of Angular. Use `$httpProvider.interceptors.push()` instead. You'd have to modify the `interceptor` as well. Anyway, thanks for the wonderful answer! :)

Comment: Thanks! We just ran into this, was like whaaaa.. lol users could by-pass our login and go to our dashboard. Luckly no user data would be loaded.

Answer (score 25):

The question is a duplicate of [AngularJS: Injecting service into a HTTP interceptor (Circular dependency)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20647483/angularjs-injecting-service-into-a-http-interceptor-circular-dependency)

I am re-posting my answer from that thread here:

## A Better Fix

I think using the $injector directly is an antipattern.

A way to break the circular dependency is to use an event:
Instead of injecting $state, inject $rootScope.
Instead of redirecting directly, do

```
this.$rootScope.$emit("unauthorized");
```

plus

```
angular
    .module('foo')
    .run(function($rootScope, $state) {
        $rootScope.$on('unauthorized', () => {
            $state.transitionTo('login');
        });
    });
```

That way you have separated the concerns:

1. Detect a 401 response
2. Redirect to login

Comment: Actually, that question is a duplicate of this question, because this question was asked before that one was. Love your elegant fix though, so have an upvote. ;-)

Comment: I'm confusing about where to put this.$rootScope.$emit("unauthorized");

Answer (score 16):

Jonathan's solution was great until I tried to save the current state. In [ui-router v0.2.10](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/tree/0.2.10) the current state does not seem to be populated on initial page load in the interceptor.

Anyway, I solved it by using the [$stateChangeError](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.%24state#%24stateChangeSuccess) event instead. The **$stateChangeError** event gives you both **to** and **from** states, as well as the error. It's pretty nifty.

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeError',
    function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, error){
        console.log('stateChangeError');
        console.log(toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, error);

        if(error.status == 401){
            console.log("401 detected. Redirecting...");

            authService.deniedState = toState.name;
            $state.go("login");
        }
    });
```

Comment: I've submitted an [issue](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1060) about this.

Comment: I think this is not possible with ngResource since it is always asynchron? I tried some stuff but I don't get the resource call to prevent a state change...

Comment: What if you want to intercept a request that does not trigger a state change?

Comment: You can use the same approach as @Stephen Friedrich did above, which actually resembles this one but uses a custom event.