# Angular, show loading when any resource is in pending

Tags: angularjs, angular-services

I already write a code to display a loader div, when any resources is in pending, no matter it's getting via $http.get or routing \ ng-view.
I wan't only information if i'm going bad...

flowHandler service:

```
app.service('flowHandler', function(){
    var count = 0;
    this.init = function() { count++ };
    this.end = function() { count-- };
    this.take = function() { return count };
});
```

The MainCTRL append into `<body ng-controller="MainCTRL">`

```
app.controller("MainCTRL", function($scope, flowHandler){
    var _this = this;
    $scope.pageTitle = "MainCTRL";
    $scope.menu = [];
    $scope.loader = flowHandler.take();

    $scope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function (event, next, current) {
        flowHandler.init();
    });

    $scope.$on("$routeChangeSuccess", function (event, next, current) {
        flowHandler.end();
    });

    updateLoader = function () {
        $scope.$apply(function(){
            $scope.loader = flowHandler.take();
        });

    };

    setInterval(updateLoader, 100);

});
```

And some test controller when getting a data via $http.get:

```
app.controller("BodyCTRL", function($scope, $routeParams, $http, flowHandler){
    var _this = this;
    $scope.test = "git";

    flowHandler.init();
    $http.get('api/menu.php').then(function(data) {
        flowHandler.end();
        $scope.$parent.menu = data.data;

    },function(error){flowHandler.end();});
});
```

now, I already inject flowHandler service to any controller, and init or end a flow.

It's good idea or its so freak bad ?

Any advice ? How you do it ?

Comment: Have a look at the source code of [angular loading bar](https://github.com/chieffancypants/angular-loading-bar). Copy the core things or just use it. (Sorry, I didn't read your question, but why would you want to invent the wheel once again?)

Comment: I want show wheel or div (loading), to inform about some data is in pending $get/$post.

Comment: plunker maybe? is this "what you want" or are you open to other ways to implement this functionality?

Comment: Yes, at this moment is "what I want" but i would like get any advice if this can be do better or if it's bad idea to do it with my solution

Comment: will you end up hiding loading when you have multiple requests and one gets first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you to take a look at $http's pendingRequest propertie

`https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http`

As the name says, its an array of requests still pending. So you can iterate this array watching for an specific URL and return true if it is still pending.
Then you could have a div showing a loading bar with a ng-show attribute that watches this function

I would also encapsulate this requests in a Factory or Service so my code would look like this:

```
//Service that handles requests
angular.module('myApp')
    .factory('MyService', ['$http', function($http){

  var Service = {};

  Service.requestingSomeURL = function(){
    for (var i = http.pendingRequests.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      if($http.pendingRequests[i].url === ('/someURL')) return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  return Service;
}]);


//Controller
angular.module('myApp')
    .controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'MyService', function($scope, MyService){

  $scope.pendingRequests = function(){
    return MyService.requestingSomeURL();
  }
}]);
```

And the HTML would be like

```
<div ng-show="pendingRequests()">
  <div ng-include="'views/includes/loading.html'"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I dont want to display loader for specific pending request but for all pendings ;) if any wait... even when angular set a promise.

Comment: You could check for `$http.pendingRequests.length` when displaying the loader. But yes, this will only return true for requests for the server. Angular promises will not count.

Answer (score 4):

You could easily implement something neat using e.g. any of [Bootstrap's progressbars](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#progress).

Let's say all your services returns `promises`.

```
// userService ($q)
app.factory('userService', function ($q) {
  var user = {};
  user.getUser = function () {
    return $q.when("meh");
  };
  return user;
});

// roleService ($resource)
// not really a promise but you can access it using $promise, close-enough :)
app.factory('roleService', function ($resource) {
  return $resource('role.json', {}, { 
    query: { method: 'GET' }
  });
});

// ipService ($http)
app.factory('ipService', function ($http) {
  return {
    get: function () { 
      return $http.get('http://www.telize.com/jsonip');
    }
  };
});
```

Then you could apply `$scope` variable (let's say "loading") in your `controller`, that is changed when all your chained promises are resolved.

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, userService, roleService, ipService) {

  _.extend($scope, {
    loading: false,
    data: { user: null, role: null, ip: null}
  });

  // Initiliaze scope data
  function initialize() {
    // signal we are retrieving data
    $scope.loading = true;

    // get user
    userService.getUser().then(function (data) {
      $scope.data.user = data;
    // then apply role
    }).then(roleService.query().$promise.then(function (data) {
      $scope.data.role = data.role;
    // and get user's ip
    }).then(ipService.get).then(function (response) {
      $scope.data.ip = response.data.ip;
    // signal load complete
    }).finally(function () {
      $scope.loading = false;
    }));
  }

  initialize();
  $scope.refresh = function () {
    initialize();
  };
});
```

Then your template could look like.

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<h3>Loading indicator example, using promises</h3>

<div ng-show="loading" class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" style="width: 100%">      
      Loading, please wait...
  </div>
</div>

<div ng-show="!loading">
  <div>User: {{ data.user }}, {{ data.role }}</div>
  <div>IP: {{ data.ip }}</div>
  <br>
  <button class="button" ng-click="refresh();">Refresh</button>
</div>
```

This gives you two "states", one for loading...

[image: imgur]

...and other for all-complete.
[image: imgur]

Of course this is not a "real world example" but maybe something to consider. You could also refactor this "loading bar" into it's own `directive`, which you could then use easily in templates, e.g.

```
//Usage: <loading-indicator is-loading="{{ loading }}"></loading-indicator>

/* loading indicator */
app.directive('loadingIndicator', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      isLoading: '@'
    },
    link: function (scope) {
      scope.$watch('isLoading', function (val) {
          scope.isLoading = val;
      });
    },
    template: '<div ng-show="isLoading" class="progress">' +
              '  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" style="width: 100%">' +
              '        Loading, please wait...' +
              '    </div>' +
              '</div>'
  };
});
```

Related plunker here http://plnkr.co/edit/yMswXU

Answer (score 2):

I'd check out this project:

http://chieffancypants.github.io/angular-loading-bar/

It auto injects itself to watch $http calls and will display whenever they are happening. If you don't want to use it, you can at least look at its code to see how it works.

Its very simple and very useful :)

Answer (score 1):

I used a base controller approach and it seems most simple from what i saw so far. Create a base controller:

```
angular.module('app')
.controller('BaseGenericCtrl', function ($http, $scope) {
    $scope.$watch(function () {
        return $http.pendingRequests.length;
    }, function () {
        var requestLength = $http.pendingRequests.length;
        if (requestLength > 0)
            $scope.loading = true;
        else
            $scope.loading = false;
    });
});
```

Inject it into a controller

```
   angular.extend(vm, $controller('BaseGenericCtrl', { $scope: $scope }));
```

I am actually also using error handling and adding authorization header using intercepting $httpProvider similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25781350/631527), and in this case you can use loading on rootScope

Answer (score 0):

I used a simpler approach:

```
var controllers = angular.module('Controllers', []);

controllers.controller('ProjectListCtrl', [ '$scope', 'Project',
    function($scope, Project) {
        $scope.projects_loading = true;
        $scope.projects = Project.query(function() {
            $scope.projects_loading = false;
        });
}]);
```

Where Project is a resource:

```
var Services = angular.module('Services', [ 'ngResource' ]);
Services.factory('Project', [ '$resource', function($resource) {
    return $resource('../service/projects/:projectId.json', {}, {
        query : {
            method : 'GET',
            params : {
                projectId : '@id'
            },
            isArray : true
        }
    });
} ]);
```

And on the page I just included:

```
 <a ng-show="projects_loading">Loading...</a>
 <a ng-show="!projects_loading" ng-repeat="project in projects">
      {{project.name}}
 </a>
```

I guess, this way, there is no need to override the $promise of the resource