# AngularJs Circular Dependency for Interceptor

Tags: angularjs, circular-dependency, angular-http-interceptors

I have the following circular dependency:

```
            $http
            /   \
           /     \
          /       \
         /         \
LoginManager------Interceptor
 (service)         (factory)
```

This Circular dependency only emerged after I added the code for Interceptor.

`Interceptor` will call the logout function in `LoginManager` in case a certain `response` in intercepted.

> From what I see, only solution is to move interceptor code inside the `LoginManager` service as an `anonymous factory`

Is there any better way?

Comment: can you post your `interceptor` and `LoginManager` code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS: Injecting service into a HTTP interceptor (Circular dependency)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20647483/angularjs-injecting-service-into-a-http-interceptor-circular-dependency)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can avoid the circular dependency by using the `injector` service to get an instance of `LoginManager` at runtime.

```
var loginManager = $injector.get('LoginManager');
```

Just make sure you use this code inside one of the methods of the interceptor (e.g `responseError`) and not directly in your interceptor creation code.

Comment: using `$injector` does not have any effect on the circular dependency.

Comment: Did you remove `LoginManager` from the dependency list of `Interceptor`?

Comment: my bad, the `$injector.get` thing needs to be inside the `return object` of the interceptor. I think it would be good if you mention it in the answer.

Comment: The last sentence in this answer saved my butt, none of the answers on SO, including the link in the comment section of the question make that clear. Thanks so much dude (I'm aware this comment is in bad form but w/e)